# VMware vCenter - Is rebooting gonna break the cluster

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We are currently working on updating our infrastructure to the latest versions of everything but now we are stuck with vCenter.

I would like to know if it is possible to update the VM appliance then reboot it without disrupting the vSphere Cluster we have. Will it continue to work during the reboot or every VM host will crash?

I tried to search on Google but even the VMware KB doesn't have any answers on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cluster and VM Guests will continue to run just fine.

Obviously management will be offline and anything that relies on the vCenter (backups that talk to the vCenter, etc) will not work until it comes back online.

Some functionality will be impaired or not function as well (DRS for sure) until the server is back online.

Comment: I confirm, and I will just add to make sure to have credential for each ESX to be able to restart the appliance in case of need (or any other VM)